# Namespace boost,Error qualified name is not allowed?

Tags: c++, boost, std

I am defining a tuple as 
 typedef boost::tuple tuple_name,where a,b and c are data types,
but iam getting the above mentioned error as "**ERROR qualified name is not allowed**,but same works fine when i defined the same tuple as std::tuple.
Can anyone please tell me what exactly is happening?Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: #include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>
typedef boost::tuple<int,double,double> myVariable;

Comment: @AnilGoudar MSVC 2015U1 compiles your code without errors or warnings.

Comment: @matb ,but in VS2013 ,the editor shows red line..thanx for your feedback